# How to observe property changed in Swift with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: swift, swift4, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am writing Swift with the new ReactiveCocoa + ReactiveSwift. I am trying to do something like the following (in ReactiveCocoa 2.5) with the new ReactiveCocoa framework:

```
[[RACObserve(user, username) skip:1] subscribeNext:^(NSString *newUserName) {
    // perform actions...
}];
```

After some researches, I still could not figure out how to do it. Please help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your snippet works via KVO which is still possible with the most recent RAC/RAS in Swift, but is **not** the recommended way anymore.

#### Using Property

The recommended way is to use `Property` which holds a value and can be observed.

Here is an example:

```
struct User {
  let username: MutableProperty<String>
  init(name: String) {
    username = MutableProperty(name)
  }
}

let user = User(name: "Jack")

// Observe the name, will fire once immediately with the current name
user.username.producer.startWithValues { print("User's name is \($0)")}
// Observe only changes to the value, will not fire with the current name
user.username.signal.observeValues { print("User's new name is \($0)")}

user.username.value = "Joe"
```

which will print

> User's name is Jack
>
> User's name is Joe
>
> User's new name is Joe

#### Using KVO

If for some reason you still need to use KVO, heres how you can do that. Keep in mind, that KVO only works on explicit subclasses of `NSObject`, and if the class is written in Swift, the property needs to be annotated with `@objc` **and** `dynamic`!

```
class NSUser: NSObject {
  @objc dynamic var username: String
  init(name: String) {
    username = name
    super.init()
  }
}

let nsUser = NSUser(name: "Jack")

// KVO the name, will fire once immediately with the current name
nsUser.reactive.producer(forKeyPath: "username").startWithValues { print("User's name is \($0)")}
// KVO only changes to the value, will not fire with the current name
nsUser.reactive.signal(forKeyPath: "username").observeValues { print("User's new name is \($0)")}

nsUser.username = "Joe"
```

which will print

> User's name is Optional(Jack)
>
> User's new name is Optional(Joe)
>
> User's name is Optional(Joe)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if the user object is an NSManagedObject? The name property is just a normal objc property.

Comment: Then use the KVO approach!